# Is there a nicer way to Cast the result of Enumerable.Range to type Double?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

To make an array of doubles starting from 1 to 10 I currently am doing:

```vb
Dim N() As Double = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(Function(x) CDbl(x)).ToArray
```

My technique seems inefficient and indirect. I see that `ToArray` has the space for arguments but whenever I try `ToArray(Double)` or `ToArray(Of Double)` it gives me an error.

What is the correct way to cast the elements to type Double when creating an array through `Enumerable.Range`?

Comment: You do the casting at `Select(Function(x) CDbl(x))`. The `ToArray` does not cast anything, it only packs the already casted result. It does not have parameters either.

Comment: Given that you have integers and need doubles, a cast is unavoidable, and it really doesn't matter how and where this cast is introduced. If you are that concerned about efficiency, allocate an array of exactly 10 elements up front and fill it with a plain old loop -- this avoids the `.ToArray()` step, which is far more costly than the double conversion (relatively speaking; of course both are still cheap and this is not worth optimizing if done once).

Comment: For completeness, of course the most "direct and efficient" way of doing this is `Dim N = New Double() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }` (or any of several equivalent ways to specify array initializers). The compiler can initialize this array in constant time; no loops or function calls. Of course this gets unwieldy if the array is supposed to have 100, or X elements, and you also need to be able to count -- a skill that can get rusty with us developers who are used to letting computers do all the work. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a nicer way to ...**

Well, *nicer* is relative - but to which quality? If performance is that quality, then avoid LINQ. If simplicity is that quality, then use LINQ.

```
Dim count = 1000000

Dim sw As New Stopwatch()

sw.Start()
Dim n = Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(Function(x) CDbl(x)).ToArray()
sw.Stop() 
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

sw.Restart()
Dim m(count - 1) As Double
For i = 0 To m.GetUpperBound(0)
    m(i) = CDbl(i + 1)
Next
sw.Stop() 
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
```

> 35
> 6

Clearly, one is cleaner, and the other faster. Which is *nicer* is up to you...

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I had no idea LINQ was so much slower. I thought it would be better/faster for array operations and applying functions to arrays.

Comment: @Toddleson: the main problem facing LINQ in this particular case is that `Enumerable.Range().Select()` and `.ToArray()` do not have any synergy under the hood, meaning that `.ToArray()` doesn't know how many elements will come in and it has to apply a strategy where it buffers elements, reallocating as it goes along. This produces multiple arrays as garbage, which is why it's expensive (along with allocating and calling delegates, though that's relatively small overhead). LINQ shines when you stick to enumerations.

Comment: Why  `m(i) = CDbl(i + 1)`? May be just `m(i) = i`.

Comment: @Jimi with the explicit cast or without (implicit) it does the same thing. I included it to clearly show a cast is performed there. But good to note that Integer widens into Double implicitly. Yeahhh and I was anal about getting the array contents the same i.e. 1 ... 1000000 instead of the for loop producing 0 ... 999999 :)

Comment: Not exactly the same thing. With `CDbl()`, you have a function call per iteration. If you do the same thing in C#, e.g., `m[i] = (double)i;`, I'm pretty sure it will tell you that the cast is redundant. `m[i] = i;` and `m[i] = i + 1D;` are the same thing (except the addition, which would be just a `ldc.r8 1` more).

Comment: @Jimi `CDbl` is not a function call, it is a cast. It is lexically redundant but introduces no more processing and is just included to clearly convey that a cast is taking place, for the purpose of this answer. It's not necessary in production.

Comment: @Jimi: the language doesn't require you to *specify* the cast, but of course the cast is still there, just implicit -- integers and doubles don't have the same representations, so a conversion must happen one way or another. And `CDbl()`, while a function call semantically, compiles to a single `conv.r8` opcode if given an `Integer`, just as a C# cast would. (At the same time `CDbl` is not actually a cast -- there are more complicated cases where `CDbl` does produce more involved code, such as when passing it a string, but that doesn't apply here.)

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Yes, I know that `C*()` functions are in-lined and probably force coercion, so the result may be the same as `conv.r8` (plus a `ldloc.x`, probably) in C#. But I'm not exactly sure how these function behave in all versions of the language and what the IL would be in all cases (if you have tested it in the IDE, let me know, I can't right now).  Anyway, the point was that an explicit cast or conversion is not required here. If there's no difference in time, better.

Comment: @Jimi: I've verified it using LINQPad; the latest versions are quite impressive when it comes to decompiling. I have no idea if there's a difference between versions (like, maybe the VB.NET 1 compiler was a lot less clever), that would require a lot more work. The language specification does not, of course, *guarantee* it will compile to a single opcode, but that's nitpicking since the C# language spec makes no guarantee a cast is "efficient" either (indeed it cannot for the general case, since user-defined conversions are a thing).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a finite length and know the numbers in advance, the most efficient way would be to create the array with the upper-bounds and set the items individually. The compiler doesn't need to infer the upper-bounds when you explicitly specify it:

```vb
Dim n(9) As Double
n(0) = 1
n(1) = 2
'etc...

' or even more concise
For counter As Integer = 1 To 0
    n(counter - 1) = counter
Next
```

An alternative would be to create the array with an explicit initialization. This is "less performant" in that the compiler has to infer the upper-bounds, though I would imagine it is a marginal performance hit:

```vb
Dim n() As Double = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
```

If you do not want to type the values out, then you can do what you're doing and create a range and then cast the result. An alternative to using `Select` would be to use the ConvertAll method:

```vb
Dim n() As Double = Array.ConvertAll(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray(), Function(counter) Convert.ToDouble(counter))
```

Long story short, what you're doing isn't wrong. If you are pinching for performance, it is not the most optimal solution, but more often than not you should be just fine.

Comment: In your experience, are there benefits to using `Array.ConvertAll` instead of `Enumerable.Select`?

Comment: I’ve found it more convenient for simple conversions, but nothing more than personal preference.

Comment: Your "less-performant" is not actually less performant. The compiler know in advance how big the array needs to be, so it's statically compiled to `Dim n(10)`